# Why can't I start a bounty on my question?

Tags: support, bounties

I am receiving the following notification:

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question? [Rails audit system with both ActiveResource and ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989378/rails-audit-system)

but there is no "start bounty" link! I can't see how to start a bounty on my question.

Comment: Might sound silly, but do you have active bounty on other question? (Yours or not, it doesn't matter) EDIT: I see you started bounty on May 14 so question is, did you grant it to someone by now?

Comment: oh yes I have opened bounrty on other question - that can be reason.. notification make me a little confused

Comment: OK, this clears things up - see my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you look in the right place? Should be available from the question page:

[image: bounty screenshot]

Edit:

Following comments, the problem is that you already have active bounty on other question.

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) mentions this as part of the "Which questions are eligible?" section but it might be good feature request to not show the notification in such case, or show the "start a bounty" link anyway and clicking it will produce message saying something like "You already have active bounty on (question here) please award it first".

Comment: there is no link/button for bounty on the question page

Comment: @Fivell see my comment on your question then..

Comment: That sounds like a good feature-request in your edit. Why not make a real feature-request out of it?

Comment: @Hendrik - I got to go now, so the stage is all yours. :-)